# Attributes from MvxBindingAttributes are not added with MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have the MvxBindingAttributes.xml in my UI.Droid/Resources/Values but everytime I try to use the bindings in my layouts I get

> Warning   attribute is not declared.
>
> No resource identifier found for attribute 'MvxBind' in package
>   'DroidUI'

so for some reason it cannot find those attributes. I have tried to close/reopen/clean/rebuild with no luck, tried removing the layouts and then building (Hoping it would add them at build) and then try to add them again, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the project properties, add a Android Manifest file and add a package name that contains at least two periods, for example:

```
com.DroidUI
```

In the axml file, type the package name instead of the namespace:

```
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.DroidUI
```

Answer (score 23):

Have you checked that the `MvxBindingAttributes.xml` file is marked in properties as an AndroidResource?

VisualStudio likes marking the xml files as content or none instead - especially if you've added the `MvxBindingAttributes.xml` file as a link.

---

As an **update** to this, you can also now use a special 'auto' xml scheme:

```
     xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

---

Comment: It is marked as AndoroidResource, I have made another project that works now, but had the same problem and suddenly it just worked and I have no clue what changed

Comment: If you can spot the difference then it would be interesting to know!

Comment: @Stuart If I do the above, the error changes to: AndroidDemo/AndroidDemo.Core/AndroidDemo.DroidUI/aapt: Error: Invalid resource directory name: "mvxbindingattributes.xml". (AndroidDemo.DroidUI)

Comment: @Stuart Thanks again, after I installed the new version of Xamarin.Android my project stopped working. Building gives errors that can't find MvxBind... I had to change my xmlns from http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/yourPackageName to http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto and now it's working!

Comment: I'm using the res-auto xml scheme, but i'm still getting a similar error: "the 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto:MvxBind' attribute is not declared"  -- It compiles and runs, but it would be nice to remove the warning.

Comment: @Steve post a full sample somewhere - e.g. in a new question - that's not an error I've seen. e.g. I don't see that error on the Mvx N+1 samples

Answer (score 4):

xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for the answer. I had the same problem.

But in my case, attempting to use the suggestions above failed. or at least that is what i thought.

When i used `local:MvxItemTemplate=@layout/My_Manifest` while i had the My_Manifest.axml file correctly placed in Layout folder, and correct xml schemas, it still had problems.

But, when i changed My_Manifest to my_manifest while leaving the actual file name as My_Manifest.axml, everything was working.

just wanted to share

Answer (score 1):

In my case for some reason the MvxBindingAttributes.xml file existed, but hadn't been included in the project. Right-clicking on MvxBindingAttributes.xml and choosing "Include in Project" sorted the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case: You might also have rubbish (in my case, it were dots) in some of your XML. But the error pointed "Maybe there's something wrong with the auto-generated XML lol" so it took me half an hour to notice it... Sigh!